# In hook_user_presave how to check if account is being activated and account is new?

Tags: 8, hooks

Currently in Drupal 7 I have two conditions in hook_user_presave,
1. Is account is being activated
2. Is account new

```
function hook_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
    if (isset($account->is_new) && !empty($account->is_new)) {
        //If account is new then execute my code here
    }

    if ((isset($account->uid)) && (isset($account->status)) && ($account->status == 0) && ($edit['status'] == 1)) {
        //If account is being activated for the first time then execute my code here
    }
}
```

I want to convert this code to Drupal 8, What should be the conditions?

```
function hook_user_presave($account) {

    //Condition 1

    //Condition 2
}
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if the user is new:

```
$account->isNew()
```

To check if the user is active:

```
$account->isActive()
```

See [User API isNew](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AisNew/8.4.x) or [User API isActive](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3AisActive/8.4.x) for more information.

Comment: It's working. I added getLastAccessedTime condition to make sure that account is being activated for the first time. Thanks a lot for links, Very helpful.