# Create a node when the user is activated

Tags: hooks

Drupal Version: 8.92

Part 1. I am trying to create a node when the user is activated by the administrator for the first time. However, I am not able to find the right event/hook to execute the code. I tried "user_activated" but it is not working.

```
function my_module_user_activated(\Drupal\user\UserInterface $user) {
  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create([
    'type' => 'my_node',
    'title' => $user->getDisplayName(),
    'uid' => $user->id(),
  ])->save();
}
```

Any pointers?

PS: I don't want to create the node using hook_user_insert().

Part 2. If I need to delay the node creation to user validating the email by clicking a URL, what hook should I try?

Thank You!
Uri

Comment: Does this answer you question? [In hook_user_presave how to check if account is being activated and account is new?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246981/in-hook-user-presave-how-to-check-if-account-is-being-activated-and-account-is-n)

Comment: I would make the node an entity ref field on the user ... then you would just need to check if the user had a node if no create it if yes do nothing ... also this code can be on the alter of the user admin form

Comment: Thanks @NoSssweat 

It makes sense to incorporate taggartJ's suggestions too. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In hook\_user\_presave how to check if account is being activated and account is new?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246981/in-hook-user-presave-how-to-check-if-account-is-being-activated-and-account-is-n)

Answer (score 1):

Modified code based on the pointers from No Sssweat. The working code is below for any future references.

```
function <MY-MODULE>_user_presave(\Drupal\user\UserInterface $user) {
  if (($user->isActive()) and ($user->getLastAccessedTime() == 0 ) and ( $user->hasRole('role_name'))){
  \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::create([
    'type' => 'my_content_type',
    'title' => $user->getDisplayName(),
    'uid' => $user->id(),
  ])->save();
  }
```

}